# Plotly subplots do not work correctly with visible: 'legendonly' plots

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I want to create a subplot similar to the first one shown in the documentation here: https://plotly.com/javascript/subplots/ with one important change. When a user clicks on the legend to hide a trace, I don't just want to hide the trace line but still keep the plot axis and grid lines visible, I want to hide that as well.

I created this code pen that demonstrates my problem: https://codepen.io/mmakrzem/pen/mdrmvyR

```
const traces = createTraces();  
  _subPlots = traces.map( ( trace, index ) => ( {
    label: trace.name,
    dataIndex: index,
    isVisible: true,
  } ) );
  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', traces, getLayout() );

  const plotEl = document.querySelector( '#myDiv' );
  plotEl.on( 'plotly_legendclick', event => {
    const isHidden = event.data[event.curveNumber].visible === 'legendonly';
    const update = {
      visible: isHidden ? true : 'legendonly', //toggle visibility of data
    };
    Plotly.restyle( plotEl.id, update, [event.curveNumber] );
    const subPlotInfo = _subPlots.find( info => info.dataIndex === event.curveNumber );
    if( subPlotInfo ) {
      subPlotInfo.isVisible = isHidden; //toggle visibility
      Plotly.relayout( plotEl.id, getLayout() );
    } else {
      console.error( `could not find subPlotInfo with dataIndex=${event.curveNumber}` );
      console.info( event );
      console.info( 'subPlots: ', _subPlots );
    }
    return false;
  } );
```

In my example, I create 4 plots rendered in 1 row and 4 columns.

Notice that if you click the 'Blue' legend, the first plot disappears, leaving only the Orange, Green and Red traces as desired.
Everything works fine with this example, so long as you hide the traces from top to bottom without skipping any.

To see the problem, turn all the traces on, and then click on 'Green' in the legend to hide the 3rd plot. This should result in the Blue, Orange and Red traces to be visible.

What I'm seeing instead is that the Blue and Orange plot axes are visible but there are no traces drawn. The Red plot is perfectly fine.

If you turn all of the traces on, and then click on 'Red" to hide the last plot, now the Red one is gone (correct) but the other 3 do not render in their appropriate spots.

Any idea's what I'm doing wrong?